# How can I display a list of results while typing, from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to do something like this

[image]

But I am not sure how to do this... Probably an ajax call while typing, but how to do it.

Comment: *"I am trying to do something like this"* - I don't see a code attempt.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding service ___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have no idea of an aproach... I was waiting for some suggestions..
I don't expect a ready to use code, I want suggestions on how to aproach this..

Comment: You could search on the internet for a solution. You maybe use a library to build this functionality.

Comment: Google "live search php mysql", here is one result http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-ajax-live-search.php and you can keep going with the keywords I left you, which will render many more hits ;-) You can also add "ajax" to that list.

Comment: @chuckyMan You wrote *"I don't expect a ready to use code, I want suggestions on how to aproach this"* - That tends to attract opionated answers and is also too broad a question. You have been given a few answers below; one with what now holds a code example and another with just that; a text-opionated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a dead-simple way to do this with **jQuery UI** as shown in this guide.
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

```js
$( function() {
    function showResults(message) {
      $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#results");
      $("#results").scrollTop(0);
    }
 
    $("#inputField").autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        showResults("Selected:" + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id);
      }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

To do this in a very similar way with Ajax, I recommend you follow this guide by 
Tom Kirda. https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: I know you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: I have seen links to the https://jqueryui.com/ website no longer exist. It's best you include the essentials bits of code, even though that that website is renowned. However, that other one may one day (soon) cease to exist. As of now, this answer is considered as being of very low-quality. Edit: *"I did not DV"* - @RiggsFolly You're right, I did.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did flag _as low quality though_

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was going to also, but have given them the benefit of the doubt till they can edit their answer. I believe I was "being nice" ;-) and I can't be called "the bad man". Not saying you're bad though *lol!*

Comment: I updated my answer to cover a little more in depth by including the actual snippet from jQuery UI. If there's anything else to improve I'd be glad to add that as well.

Comment: @VictorWesterlund That is much better Victor.